# Extract gmail email address from tab using content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need user's logged in `email id` in `mail.google.com`.

**manifest.json(relevant part):**

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
      "css":["content/content.css"],
      "js":["lib/jquery/jquery.min.js","content/contentScript.js"],
      "all_frames":true,
      "run_at":"document_end"
    }
  ]
```

Actually I am passing a message from `background` to `content script`, when message is received then i call `var email = $(".gb_8a").html()`. I send message after user selects a text from a mail and clicks on a `context menu`, so at the point of sending message `gmail ui` is already loaded.

**contentScript.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        switch (request.type){
            case "getEmail":
                $("#loader").show();
                var email = $(".gb_8a").html();
                sendResponse({success:true, email:email});
                break;
              }  
    });
```

It was working till yesterday but now I am getting `undefined`. However `div` with class `gb_8a` still exists with required `email id` then why i am not able to access it??

Comment: Because `document_end` occurs at `DOMContentLoaded` but the gmail site builds and initializes its UI after that.

Comment: @wOxxOm that's not the case. I edited the question. plz check

Comment: The content scripts is executed in all iframes and only the main page has the element. Just add a check if the element exists and only send the response in that case.

Comment: I removed all_frames = true. It works now

Comment: @Sid can you look at this, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258961/find-the-logged-in-gmail-user-email-address . I need to extract the email address and get that email address in popup.