# find the logged in gmail user email address

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on chrome extension which is focused only for gmail messages. The extension is used only in the gmail messages but for this i need to find out the logged in users email address. I have created the login functionality to use the extension in the popup and I need "logged in users email address" to check if the user that is logging in the extension matches with that email address or not.

I tried two things in the background script(background.js).

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({ domain: 'accounts.google.com' }, function(cookies) {
    console.log('accounts.google.com cookies', cookies);
});

chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(profile) {
    console.log('profile', profile);
});
```

1st method gives me an empty array

2nd method gives me an object of empty email and id

Can anyone help me in providing the reliable solution for finding the logged in user's email address, please?

UPDATE

I found that `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(profile) {` this gives me the email that is registered in chrome not of the logged in gmail email address.

Comment: I hope this is not possible. You should register an application in google and let the user login using OAuth in your extension with the account he or she wants to use. Other than that I guess you can try to read it from the DOM when the user is on the gmail site.

Comment: Can you help me showing a bit of sample, please?

Answer (score 1):

Add Permissions "identity.email" and "cookies" in manifest.json.